# Mongo ID object with PHP library

Tags: php, mongodb

I can not find any reference to creating a new MogoId istance with the new PHP library.  With the legacy driver you would use `new MongoId($id)` however with the new php library, this class does not exist.

Comment: which driver? can you show a link?

Comment: Using the latest mongodb driver and the php library from composer.

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging through the driver source, it is called like so:

```
new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id);
```